# Bash shell - count and display the list of directories and sub-directories in chronologicall order

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Shell-program to count and display the list of Directories in chronological order (by modification date, for example) in sub-trees beginning with directory name is given
Expected form output results:

```
directory <directory name>--| <--initial directory
catalog <name>--------------|   
----------------------------| <--directories in the current directory
catalog <name>--------------|


directory <directory name>--| <--sub-directory
catalog <name>--------------|   
----------------------------| <--directories in the current directory
catalog <name>--------------|

----------------------------

and etc.
```

Here's I have found script to recursively list directories and sub-directories and modification date. But how to sort it in chronological order and level of nestings?

```
#!/bin/bash

#script to recursively travel a dir of n levels

function traverse() {   
    for folderin $(ls "$1")
    do
        if [[ ! -f ${1}/${folder} ]]; then
        stat="$(date -r ${1}/${folder} +"%F %T")"
            echo "${1}/${folder} ${stat}"
            traverse "${1}/${folder}"
        fi
    done
}

function main() {
    traverse "$1"
}

main "$1"
```

Thank you very much.
Have a nice day.

P.S. Output format something like that - separated by nesting level and in chronological order:

```
1 level:
/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir2/

2 level:
/dir1/dir1/
/dir1/dir2/
/dir1/dir3/

/dir2/dir1/
/dir2/dir2/
/dir2/dir3/

/dir3/dir1/
/dir3/dir2/
/dir3/dir3/

3 level:
/dir1/dir1/dir1/
/dir1/dir1/dir2/
/dir1/dir1/dir3/

/dir1/dir2/dir1/
/dir1/dir2/dir2/
/dir1/dir2/dir3/

/dir1/dir3/dir1/
/dir1/dir3/dir2/
/dir1/dir3/dir3/

etc.
```

OR

```
1 level:
/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir2/

2 level:
/dir1/dir1/
/dir1/dir2/
/dir1/dir3/

3 level:
/dir1/dir1/dir1/
/dir1/dir1/dir2/
/dir1/dir1/dir3/

2 level:
/dir2/dir1/
/dir2/dir2/
/dir2/dir3/

3 level:
/dir1/dir2/dir1/
/dir1/dir2/dir2/
/dir1/dir2/dir3/

2 level:
/dir3/dir1/
/dir3/dir2/
/dir3/dir3/

3 level:
/dir1/dir3/dir1/
/dir1/dir3/dir2/
/dir1/dir3/dir3/

etc.
```

not too important, just not to mix levels of nesting like that:

```
/dir1/
/dir1/dir1/
/dir1/dir1/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir1/dir2/
/dir1/dir1/dir1/
/dir3/
/dir3/dir1/
/dir1/dir3/dir1/
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the directories in order or the files or both ?

Comment: Use this command tree -d -f -t

Comment: @123, only directories. This script I modified was wrote for files, and I leaved names without changes. Will update now.

Comment: You can use the sort features that `ls` offers through its command-line options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using the `find` command or `tree -d -t -f`

this a temp structure which i have created(ls -R = list recursively)

```
~/temp$ ls -R
.:
dir1/  dir2/  dir3/  file1

./dir1:
catalog1

./dir2:

./dir3:
```

Now you can try using `find` command as follows:

`find . -type d -exec ls -dlrt {} \;` to get the list
OR
`find . -type d -exec ls -dlrt {} \; | wc --lines` to get the count

EDIT 1: to get only the top level directories you can add the `-maxdepth` and iteratively give depth values to it such as

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ls -dlrt {} \;` to get the list
OR
`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ls -dlrt {} \; | wc --lines` to get the count

**-----------------------------------------------IGNORE ABOVE STUFF---------------------------------------------------**

EDIT 2:

I see, now i get your question .. well i made a bash script to accomplish your task .. you'll need

- to maintain a queue to store your own order of processing
- and use the `find` command which i mentioned above as well

Below is the ~/temp directory structure which i made

```
$ ls -R temp
temp:
dir1/  dir2/  dir3/  file1

temp/dir1:
dir3/  dir4/

temp/dir1/dir3:

temp/dir1/dir4:

temp/dir2:
dir/  dir4/  dir5/  dir6/

temp/dir2/dir:
newdir/

temp/dir2/dir/newdir:

temp/dir2/dir4:

temp/dir2/dir5:

temp/dir2/dir6:

temp/dir3:
```

Well here is the bash script .. remove the comments/debugging_echo's if you think they are too much.
I've tried to explain the logic in the script itself (using comments).

```
#!/bin/bash
declare front_element="./temp"
#dir to start with
declare -a q=($(find "$front_element" -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -path "$front_element" -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort | awk '{print $2}'))
#initial queue population
declare -a temp_arr

if [[ ${#q[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "%s%s contains %d child directories(last modified time sort): \n" "----->" "$front_element" "${#q[@]}"
else
    printf "%s%s contains the following %d child directories(last modified time sort): \n" "----->" "$front_element" "${#q[@]}"
fi

printf "\t%s\n" "${q[@]}"

while [[ ${#q[@]} -ne 0 ]]
do
    front_element="${q[0]}"
    #Queue fetching front element
    #echo "$front_element is front_element"

    q=("${q[@]:1}")
    #actual queue dequeue operation=>reduction in size

    temp_arr=($(find "$front_element" -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -path "$front_element" -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort | awk '{print $2}'))
    #excluding self during find using -not -path self, %Tk=last modified time printed in k format(here used @=>time in seconds since UTC/Unix Epoch Jan 1, 1970 midnight along with fractional part), %p=found path, sort=>uses last modified time to sort and it sorts alphabetically if same last modified time for >=2 directories(highly unlikely as it has fractional part too)

    if [[ ${#temp_arr[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
        printf "%s%s contains %d child directories. \n" "----->" "$front_element" "${#temp_arr[@]}"
    else
        printf "%s%s contains the following %d child directories(last modified time sorted): \n" "----->" "$front_element" "${#temp_arr[@]}"
    fi
    #displaying the count as well

    if [[ ${#temp_arr[@]} -gt 0 ]]
    then
        printf "\t%s\n" "${temp_arr[@]}"
        echo
        for element in "${temp_arr[@]}"
        do
            q+=("$element")
        done
    fi
    #appending newly found stuff to the current queue for further processing

    #echo "${q[@]} is q at end of iteration"
    #echo "${temp_arr[@]} is temp_arr at end of iteration"
done
```

And here is the output of above bash script (run in the dir above your root directory)
For me my $PWD/current_dir is ~ i.e $HOME  **because** my temp directory is present here i.e parent of temp dir is $HOME

PS: it isn't thoroughly tested.

Here is the output the way you mentioned in your **1st structure** after your question edit.

```
$ ./script.bash 
----->./temp contains the following 3 child directories(last modified time sort): 
    ./temp/dir3
    ./temp/dir1
    ./temp/dir2
----->./temp/dir3 contains 0 child directories. 
----->./temp/dir1 contains the following 2 child directories(last modified time sorted): 
    ./temp/dir1/dir3
    ./temp/dir1/dir4

----->./temp/dir2 contains the following 4 child directories(last modified time sorted): 
    ./temp/dir2/dir4
    ./temp/dir2/dir5
    ./temp/dir2/dir6
    ./temp/dir2/dir

----->./temp/dir1/dir3 contains 0 child directories. 
----->./temp/dir1/dir4 contains 0 child directories. 
----->./temp/dir2/dir4 contains 0 child directories. 
----->./temp/dir2/dir5 contains 0 child directories. 
----->./temp/dir2/dir6 contains 0 child directories. 
----->./temp/dir2/dir contains the following 1 child directories(last modified time sorted): 
    ./temp/dir2/dir/newdir

----->./temp/dir2/dir/newdir contains 0 child directories.
```

PPS: ive hardcoded the root dir './temp', you need to change it to your root dir

Comment: Thanks, @ritesht93. But `find . -type d -exec ls -dlrt {} \; to get the list` lists recursively. I need all top level directories first, then nested. For example, dir1/  & dir2/  & dir3/. Then dir1/dir1/ & dir1/dir2/ & dir1/dir3/. Then dir1/dir1/ dir1/  &  dir1/dir1//dir2/ & dir1/dir1/dir3 etc.

Comment: `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec ls -dlrt {} \;` allows to limit nesting level. Great. Now I need to figure it out how to place it in some loop to iterate all folders. Thanks  @ritesht93

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, so im assuming you want to .. get the 1st dir in the sorted list, list its contents recursively  by increasing depth by 1 each time and then move onto 2nd item in the sorted list and so on.. right?

Comment: please, read my edited text after P.S. in original message. Thanks. Tried to show what I mean. Main idea - just not to mix nesting levels, separate in some way. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer, have a look

Comment: Thanks you so much @ritesht93!!! Sorry for the delay in answer. Great job. Have a nice day!!!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding :)